# Images in my Click Info box are not appearing in both published CartoDB layers

Tags: carto, layers, image, infowindow

I'm using the simple web version of CartoDB. I uploaded two datasets, each is a layer and both have the same image URL type (URLS for .png Twitter account images). When I visualise the maps individually, the images appear fine so I know the problem is not with the URLs themselves, but for reasons unknown only one set of images (blue points) displays in the published map - see here: https://drarnakarick.cartodb.com/viz/de49f3ca-cbac-11e5-a9f3-0ecd1babdde5/embed_map

How do I make it so both layers display properly. I've chosen layers because the content/columns differ between datasets.

The custom HTML for the info window (format is the same for both):

```
<div class="cartodb-popup header with-image v1" data-cover="true">
<a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
<div class="cartodb-popup-header">
    <div class="cover">
      <div id="spinner"></div>
      <div class="image_not_found"> <i></i> 
      <a href="#/map" class="help"> </a></div>
      <span class="separator"></span>
      <h1 class="order1"></h1>
      <div class="none"></div>   
      <img src="{{images}}" style="height:138px;display:inline" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <h4>Company Name</h4>
      <p><strong>{{compname}}</strong></p>
      <h4>Headquarters</h4>
      <p>{{headquarters}}</p>
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
      <h4>Official Website</h4>
      <p><a href=”{{website}}”>{{website}}</a></p>
      <h4>Twitter Profile</h4>
      <p><a href=”{{twitterurl}}”>{{twitterhandle}}</a> </p>
      <h4>Other Locations</h4>
      <p>{{otherlocations}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your issue has to do with a known bug that reorders the position of the interactivity columns in custom infowindows. Perhaps the bug is just affecting one of the layers. I recommend to take a look at my response here: [Cartodb image header doesn't show up after publishing the map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158432/cartodb-image-header-doesnt-show-up-after-publishing-the-map)

I took a look at your interactivity data for your layers and indeed, the columns are being ordered alphabetically. In the blue ones the infowindows work because, luckily, your image column name is the first one that comes out alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by calling my the image column 'animageurl' so that is appears first. The columns do default to being ordered alphabetically.